# TypeError when using filter()

Tags: filter, formatting, typeerror

I'm trying to output a string listing all the even numbers appearing in the input string.

So, an example input would be:
1 2 2 3 3 3 4

So the output should be:
[2, 2, 4]

Here's my code attempt, but it gives out a type error:

```
print(list(filter(lambda num: num%2==0, input().split())))

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
print(list(filter(lambda num: int(num)%2==0, input().split())))
```

Since the numbers are of type string the modulo operation fails.

```
>>> "2"%2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```